# remove blue glow around ListItem in ListView (android)

Tags: android, eclipse, listview, layout

I want to get rid of this horrible blue HOLO glow around my listitems when clicked.

I have:

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/projects_list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        android:paddingRight="0dp"
        android:scrollbars="none" />
```

but it still looks like this: 
http://www.roji.be/IMG_0001.png

UPDATE:
ok my app them is :

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:style/Theme.Light">
<item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/gradient_bg</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

And each listitem is wrapped in a LinearLayout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.axxes.netinc"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/listitemshadow" //9patch shadow 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="8dp" >
```

Comment: I am not able to replicate you problem with the above code. The problem must be somewhere else. Are you using a custom selector for your custom listview??

Comment: I updated the question, I think maybe it has something todo with the background of the listitem when the item is pressed (because of the padding I applied to obtain spacing between the listitems)

Answer (score 2):

set fading edge of listview to none.

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/projects_list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:fadingEdge="none" />
```

Comment: I added my own slide listeners to the baseadaptor and called the onitemselected manually and also set v.setPressed(true); so the selector will pick it up. now I don't have the borders anymore

Answer (score 0):

To remove blue glow completely:

android:overScrollMode="never"
place this attribute inside listview.
To change glow color add this code in application class

```
int glowDrawableId = getResources().getIdentifier("overscroll_glow", "drawable", "android");
        int edgeDrawableId = getResources().getIdentifier("overscroll_edge", "drawable", "android");
        Drawable androidGlow = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, glowDrawableId);
        Drawable androidEdge = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, edgeDrawableId);
        androidGlow.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.white_20), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        androidEdge.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.white_20), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

Answer (score 0):

just add `android:overScrollMode="never"` in your listview.

```
        <ListView
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/listview"
            tools:listitem="@layout/row_item"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:overScrollMode="never">
        </ListView>
```