# Remove overscroll glow in android?

Tags: android, listview, scroll, glow

In my application I am implementing the JasonFry overscroll listview, though I want to get rid of the annoying blue glow that appears on the scroll function. It seems very odd that it is so complicated to remove this... Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Set over scroll mode never on your list view, will remove all the over scroll effects.

Comment: I want my listview to overscroll; i just don't want the glow

Comment: Then you're going to have to subclass it and implement your own over scroll effect. :)

Comment: I found a great library on GitHub-- "Android Alliance Edge Override Effect"!! Highly reccomend

Answer (score 1):

like I answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32137992/1551603)
To remove blue glow completely:

android:overScrollMode="never"
place this attribute inside listview.
To change glow color add this code in application class

```
int glowDrawableId = getResources().getIdentifier("overscroll_glow", "drawable", "android");
        int edgeDrawableId = getResources().getIdentifier("overscroll_edge", "drawable", "android");
        Drawable androidGlow = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, glowDrawableId);
        Drawable androidEdge = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, edgeDrawableId);
        androidGlow.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.white_20), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        androidEdge.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.white_20), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```